# Is it normal that select.epoll consumes half of system time in mProfile result?

Tags: python

I am trying to optimize a python backend server. A simple cProfile following [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318204046/http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdywg/) shows half of system time is spent on select.poll.

[image]

Here is another profile result of an empty flask web server. 
Here is the server code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

[image]

**Question:**

1) Why my code uses lots of select.poll() whereas default Flask web server doesn't use select.poll()?

I seriously suspect that my code has performance issue (it is slow when running) due to bad architecture, but I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

It's not surprising. If an application is event-driven, it will spend most of its time just waiting for events to occur. It's just sitting in `select.poll()`, doing nothing until some data arrives on one of the file descriptors. When something arrives it processes it, then goes back to the main loop that calls `select.poll()`.

Comment: so does calling select.poll() in a loop consuming too much CPU cycle? I know if I try while(true) {} in browser console, it will crash my browser.

Comment: No. `select.poll()` is an interface to the OS `epoll()` system call, which puts the process to sleep until something happens.

Comment: As I said, the process is doing *nothing*, not looping.

Comment: I updated my question to respond to your "OS epoll() system call, which puts the process to sleep until something happens". Why default Flask web server does not use select.poll()? Is Flask way better?

Comment: You should look at the Flask source code to see how it works. There are other ways to block a process while waiting for something to happen.